# How to put a file of ads to scroll through (not AdSense) in a Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

One of the sites I oversee is written in Ruby on Rails, which I am unfamiliar with. We want to add two or three advertisements to users' duplicated profiles. These would be ads we sell to specific companies and design the ad for, not through something like AdSense. There is a development server, but I am still getting it up to date with the production server as previous devs didn't keep the server or the github for it up to date and did changes directly to production, so I am very hesitant about messing around to try to find what works. I want to know the most efficient way to have a file of self-made ads that can be pulled from the file and into the duplicated pages.

Version info:
ruby 2.4.0
rails 5.0.7.2
bootstrap 3.3.7

I looked into how to pull a database of sorts of self-created ads, but most of what I got back was referencing gems for AdSense. I feel the duplicated aspect of the profiles also complicates it. The creation of this site has some of the duplicated aspects in a layouts folder, some are in the application, and I'm not sure what would be a clean and efficient way of achieving these ads. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: your first job on this project should be to clean up the mess you have inherited, make the production and dev servers and github consistent. Then make sure that every change you make is first, before you change anything, fully covered by tests. This will not be appreciated by your management, but the alternative is far worse.